# Unable to determine the serialization information IIF

Tags: c#, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a price range query I'm trying to write for my C# code and depending on the currency type of the product I need to query the correct field

```
var minPrice = builder.Gte(s => s.Price.CurrencyCode == "USD" ? s.Price.Usd : s.Price.Foreign, filter.MinPrice);
var maxPrice = builder.Lte(s => s.Price.CurrencyCode == "USD" ? s.Price.Usd : s.Price.Foreign, filter.MaxPrice);
```

but when I run the code to test this I get the following error:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for s => IIF((s.Price.CurrencyCode == ""USD""), s.Price.Usd, s.Price.Foreign).

if I take the ternary out and just look for the US price it works perfectly, but I need to be able to have it look for non US prices as well, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going on here (I think this kind of query is just not supported yet) but how about you rewrite the query like so:

```
    var minPrice = (builder.Where(s => s.Price.CurrencyCode == "USD") & builder.Gte(s => s.Price.Usd, filter.MinPrice))
                 | (builder.Where(s => s.Price.CurrencyCode != "USD") & builder.Gte(s => s.Price.Foreign, filter.MinPrice));
    var maxPrice = (builder.Where(s => s.Price.CurrencyCode == "USD") & builder.Lte(s => s.Price.Usd, filter.MaxPrice))
                 | (builder.Where(s => s.Price.CurrencyCode != "USD") & builder.Lte(s => s.Price.Foreign, filter.MaxPrice));
```